# Knock-out If binding destroys accordion, how to reapply accordion?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/46LXU/7/

I am using jqAccordion custom binding handler to build accordion from observable array

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jqAccordion = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            console.log(element);
            //var options = valueAccessor() || {};
            //Wait for the element to build before applying accordion
            var valueAccessor1 = {heightStyle: 'content', navigation: true, collapsible: true, active: false};
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(element).accordion(valueAccessor1)
            }, 100);

            //Sense whether value is updated when sorting and them apply accordion effect
            $(element).bind('valuechanged', function () {
                ko.bindingHandlers.jqAccordion.update(element, valueAccessor1);
            });

            ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
                $(element).accordion("destroy");
            });

        },
        //Runs on every update
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            console.log(element);
            //var options = valueAccessor() || {};
            var valueAccessor = {heightStyle: 'content', navigation: true, collapsible: true, active: false};
            //condition to check whether ui accordion is defined before applying it to UI element
            if(typeof $(element).data("ui-accordion") != "undefined"){
            $(element).accordion('destroy').accordion({heightStyle: 'content', navigation: true, active: false});
            }

        }

    };
```

jQuery UI accordion is applied perfectly first when the bindings are applied as shown in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/46LXU/7/

However if i use knockout if binding to remove and reinsert the DOM element the accordion destroys but it is not recreated.

I use containerless if binding as shown below, controled by `checked` binding of checkboxes as shown below

```
 <!-- ko foreach: sections -->
<label class="pull-left"><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: hide" /> Hide </label><br />
 <!--/ko -->

<div id="mobprev" data-bind="foreach: { data: sections, afterAdd: function(elem){jQuery(elem).trigger('valuechanged')} }, jqAccordion: {active: false, heightStyle: 'content', navigation: true}">
 <!-- ko ifnot: hide -->
        <h3><a href="#" data-bind="text: section_name">HTML5</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p data-bind="html: data">Data</p>
        </div>
 <!--/ko -->

</div>
```

If  i create a new element dynamically, the `afterAdd` creates a new element with accordion applied automatically but when i hide and show the element the accordion destroys.

How to reapply jquery accordion when an element is shown after hiding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements added after the accordion creation are not integrated into it automatically.
In your case, you have to find a way to rebuild the widget when the `hide` property of any section changes.

**Example**: create a subscrition in the main vm that is triggered whenever a section is hidden/shown. The jqAccordion bindingHandler can then use it to refresh the accordion when needed.

> [***`Demo: JSFiddle`***](http://jsfiddle.net/46LXU/8/)

### vm:

```
my.vm = {
    // observable array of sections
    sections: ...
    hideall: ...
    load: ...
    subscribe: function(handler) {
        $.each(my.vm.sections(), function(index, section) {
            section.hide.subscribe(function(value) {
                handler(section, value);
            });
        });
    }
```

### bindingHandler:

```
...

//Sense whether value is updated when sorting and them apply accordion effect
$(element).bind('valuechanged', function () {
    ko.bindingHandlers.jqAccordion.update(element, valueAccessor1);
});

// viewmodel to subscribe to its changes to rebuild the widget
var vm = allBindings.get('jqAccordionViewmodel');
if(vm) {
    vm.subscribe(function(item, value) {                    
        ko.bindingHandlers.jqAccordion.update(element, valueAccessor1);
    });
}
...
```

### Html:

```
<div id="mobprev" data-bind="foreach: {
                                 data: sections, 
                                 afterAdd: function(elem) {
                                     jQuery(elem).trigger('valuechanged')
                                 }
                             },
                             jqAccordion: {
                                 active: false,
                                 heightStyle: 'content',
                                 navigation: true
                             },
                             jqAccordionViewmodel: $root">
```